# What is the type of Python's code object?

Tags: python, compilation, cpython, python-internals

Is there a way I can compare to the type of a code object constructed by `compile` or `__code__` to the actual code object type?

This works fine:

```py
>>> code_obj = compile("print('foo')", '<string>', 'exec')
>>> code_obj
<code object <module> at 0x7fb038c1ab70, file "<string>", line 1>
>>> print(type(code_obj))
code
>>> def foo(): return None
>>> type(foo.__code__) == type(code_obj)
True
```

But I can't do this:

```py
>>> type(foo.__code__) == code
NameError: name 'code' is not defined
```

but *where* do I import `code` from?

It doesn't seem to be from [code.py](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html). It's defined in the CPython [`C` file](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3b3b83c965447a8329b34cb4befe6e9908880ee5/Objects/codeobject.c) but I couldn't find the `Python` interface type for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're after [`CodeType`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3782497cc22e70b41e32ac09cb06d3948074d8a7/Lib/types.py#L14) which can be found in `types`.

```
>>> from types import CodeType
>>> def foo(): pass
... 
>>> type(foo.__code__) == CodeType
True
```

Note that [there's nothing special](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/types.py#L14) about it, it just uses `type` on a functions `__code__`.

Since it's in the standard lib, you can be sure it will work even if some change happens in the way code objects are exposed.